# Compare date from Excel file to Get-Date

Tags: powershell

I am importing Excel file which contains date I want to compare Excel date with current date.

```
$array = Import-Excel -Path 'D:\Client\HDB\test\test.xlsx' 
if ($array.'When Created' -lt Get-Date) {
    Write-Host ("true")
}
```

I expect the output as true or false then I will get that whole row and export to another Excel file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Question is not that clear, but depending on my understanding I am providing 2 solutions here.

1. Comparing the excel file created date with current date.

   ```
   $filedate = (Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\Users\Narayana\Desktop\temp.txt").CreationTime

   if ($filedate -lt (Get-Date)) {
       Write-Host true
   } else {
       Write-Host false
   }
   ```
2. Comparing the date column (in Excel sheet) with the current date

   Created a sample Excel file with the below data:

   ```
   Date,Names,Roll No
   11/6/2019,John,123456
   11/13/2019,Snehan,12546
   11/5/2019,Parda,12547
   11/20/2019,Win,14521
   ```

   - Import Excel Module

     ```
     Install-Module -Name ImportExcel -RequiredVersion 5.4.0
     ```
   - Path for Excel file

     ```
     $array = Import-Excel -Path "C:\Users\Narayana\Desktop\temp.xlsx"
     ```
   - Comparing the date which is present in the Excel file

     ```
     if ($array[1].Date -lt (Get-Date)) {
         Write-Host true
     } else {
         Write-Host false
     }
     ```

Sample output for Excel row values:

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Curious, is there a reason you're requiring v5.4? The latest is v6.5.2 https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/ImportExcel/6.5.2